# WinSock 2.2: accept() causes virus found

Tags: winsock

I made a Windows program with WinAPI and WinSock 2.2. But when I call the accept() function and compile the program, AntiVir tells me that it found a virus ("BDS/Backdoor.Gen") im my application.

This are the important parts of my code:

```
...

DWORD WINAPI winMsgServerAcceptThread(LPVOID);

SOCKET      mSocket;
SOCKET      mSocket2;
WSADATA     wsaData;
sockaddr_in socketService;

...

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ...

    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WINMSG_WM_INITSOCKET:
        {
            int wsaErr = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
            if(wsaErr != 0)
            {
                swprintf(statusBuffer, 10000, L"%s\r\n\r\nError: WSAStartup() returned code 0x%x!", statusBuffer, WSAGetLastError());
                SendMessage(hwnd, WINMSG_WM_UPDATE_STATUS, 0, 0);
                WSACleanup();
                return 0;
            }

            if(LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2  ||  HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2)
            {
                swprintf(statusBuffer, 10000, L"%s\r\n\r\nError: System doesn't support WinSock version 2.2!", statusBuffer);
                SendMessage(hwnd, WINMSG_WM_UPDATE_STATUS, 0, 0);
                WSACleanup();
                return 0;
            }

            mSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
            if(mSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                swprintf(statusBuffer, 10000, L"%s\r\n\r\nError: socket() returned code 0x%x!", statusBuffer, WSAGetLastError());
                SendMessage(hwnd, WINMSG_WM_UPDATE_STATUS, 0, 0);
                closesocket(mSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 0;
            }

            //Read own IP
            wchar_t ownIPWC[20];
            hostent *thisHost = gethostbyname("");
            strcpy(ownIP, inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)*thisHost->h_addr_list));
            mbstowcs(ownIPWC, ownIP, 20);

            swprintf(statusBuffer, 10000, L"%s\r\n\r\nSocket with IP %s successfully initialized!", statusBuffer, ownIPWC);
            SendMessage(hwnd, WINMSG_WM_UPDATE_STATUS, 0, 0);

            return 0;
        }

        ...

        case WINMSG_WM_CREATE_CONNECTION:
        {
            wchar_t serverIPString[20];

            swprintf(statusBuffer, 10000, L"%s\r\n\r\nEstablish connection...", statusBuffer);
            SendMessage(hwnd, WINMSG_WM_UPDATE_STATUS, 0, 0);

            socketService.sin_family = AF_INET;
            socketService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(WINMSG_RECV_IP);
            socketService.sin_port = htons(WINMSG_STD_PORT);

            if(connect(mSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&socketService, sizeof(socketService)) == SOCKET_ERROR)                   //Am I client?
            {
                closesocket(mSocket);
                mSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
                socketService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ownIP);
                mbstowcs(serverIPString, ownIP, 20);
                if(bind(mSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&socketService, sizeof(socketService)) == SOCKET_ERROR)                  //No, I am server
                {
                    swprintf(statusBuffer, 10000, L"%s\r\n\r\nError: bind() returned code 0x%x!", statusBuffer, WSAGetLastError());
                    SendMessage(hwnd, WINMSG_WM_UPDATE_STATUS, 0, 0);
                    closesocket(mSocket);
                    WSACleanup();
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(listen(mSocket, 10) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    {
                        swprintf(statusBuffer, 10000, L"%s\r\n\r\nError: listen() returned code 0x%x!", statusBuffer, WSAGetLastError());
                        SendMessage(hwnd, WINMSG_WM_UPDATE_STATUS, 0, 0);
                        closesocket(mSocket);
                        WSACleanup();
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        swprintf(statusBuffer, 10000, L"%s\r\n\r\nlisten() successful! Wait for client...", statusBuffer);
                        SendMessage(hwnd, WINMSG_WM_UPDATE_STATUS, 0, 0);
                        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, winMsgServerAcceptThread, 0, 0, &winMsgServerAcceptThreadID);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                swprintf(statusBuffer, 10000, L"%s\r\n\r\nConnection with %s:%d established!", statusBuffer, serverIPString, WINMSG_STD_PORT);
                connectionAvailable = 1;
                SendMessage(hwnd, WINMSG_WM_UPDATE_STATUS, 0, 0);
                return 0;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
}       

DWORD WINAPI winMsgServerAcceptThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    mSocket2 = SOCKET_ERROR;
    while(mSocket2 == SOCKET_ERROR)
        mSocket2 = accept(mSocket, NULL, NULL);

    closesocket(mSocket);
    SendMessage(hwnd, WINMSG_WM_CLIENT_ACCEPTED, NULL, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

If I delete the accept()-function in "winMsgServerAcceptThread", the program can be executed and no virus is detected.

What do I have to change to make my program not longer detected by AntiVir?

**EDIT 1:**
Here is a shortened and smaller version of the program above:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#pragma comment (lib, "wsock32.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

int main()
{
    SOCKET mSocket;
    SOCKET acceptSocket;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    sockaddr_in socketService;
    int     wsaErr;
    wchar_t serverIP[50];

    wsaErr = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if(wsaErr == 0)
        printf("Winsock DLL found!\n");

    mSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(mSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
        printf("socket() successful!\n");

    socketService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socketService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    socketService.sin_port = htons(55555);

    if(bind(mSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&socketService, sizeof(socketService)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("bind() with 127.0.0.1:55555 successful!\n");

    if(listen(mSocket, 10) != SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("listen() successful!\nWait for client...\n");

    while(1)
    {
        acceptSocket = SOCKET_ERROR;
        while(acceptSocket == SOCKET_ERROR)
            acceptSocket = accept(mSocket, NULL, NULL);
        break;
    }

    mSocket = acceptSocket;

    printf("Connected with client!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your accept thread, do not overwrite mSocket with AcceptSocket, unless you close mSocket first. They are two distinct sockets that need to be managed separately. You are using a single mSocket variable to manage multiple connections under different conditions, and that is not a good design choice.

Comment: OK, I edited the code and now use a second socket (mSocket2) to accept. But there is still the same problem!

Comment: There is a high chance this is a signature glitch in AntiVir. I know at one point in time writing a blank binary with NASM (instantly return upon execution) caused AVG to think it was a Trojan. The solution was to just email them and let them know.

Comment: Also, having antivirus enabled while programming is usually an antipattern as anti-viruses generally scan all new processes in-memory before they execute, making compilation tasks run much slower.

Comment: @StackerJ Can you please post a minimal example that recreates this issue?

Comment: I added a smaller example, but when running this program no message of AntiVir appears, although it uses the same accept()-function!

Comment: I now detected another possible source for the issue: If I call the functions connect() and bind() in one program (with accept()), a message of AntiVir appears, but if I delete one of these functions, the program can be executed correctly. But I want to have a program that represents both client and server. Could that be done another way?